# What is the difference between these properties declarations?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I see that i can declare public properties in two ways. Both of them have get / set accessors, but what is the difference between them?

```
class Job
{
    public int Interval { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

```
class Job1
{
    public int Interval = 0;
    public string Key = string.Empty;
}
```

[image]

Comment: *i can declare public **properties** in two ways* - this is simply wrong, unless you mean **members**.

Comment: You are destroying my points! just kidding :) I got the idea now

Answer (score 6):

First example is a `property` - it has declared `getter` and `setter` methods.

The second example is a public `field`, not a `property`. Public fields are  bad coding practice.